# Reference property error/app engine won't render page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, jinja2

I modeled a one to many relationship where one user can sell many things.

On the sell page, I have the user input user info: first_name, last_name, email

and item info for what they want to sell: item_name, item_price, item_tag.

Am I not using reference property right? When localhost runs the page is blank.

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    first_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    last_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required = True)

class SellModel(db.Model):
    user = ReferenceProperty(UserModel, collection_name = "sells")

    item_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    item_price = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    item_tag = db.StringProperty(required = True)

class Sell(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("sell.html")

def post(self):
    item_name = self.request.get('item_name')
    item_price = self.request.get('item_price')
    item_tag = self.request.get('item_tag')

    first_name = self.request.get('first_name')
    last_name = self.request.get('last_name')
    email = self.request.get('email')


    if item_name and item_price and item_tag and first_name and last_name and email:

        user = UserModel(key_name = "user", 
                first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name, 
                email = email)
        user.put()


        sell = SellModel(user = user, item_name = item_name, item_price = item_price, item_tag = item_tag)
        sell.put()

        stat = "your item has been recorded"
        self.render("sell.html", stat = stat)

    else:
        error = "make sure you fill out every box"
        self.render("sell.html", 
                    item_name = item_name, item_price = item_price, item_tag = item_tag,
                    first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name,
                    email = email, error=error)
```

sell.html:

```
<form method="post">
        <label>item name</label>
        <input type="text" name="item_name" value="{{item_name}}">


        <label>item price</label>
        <input type="text" name="item_price" value="{{item_price}}">


        <label>tag</label>
        <input type="text" name="item_tag" value="{{item_tag}}">


        <label>first name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{first_name}}">


        <label>last name</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{last_name}}">


        <label>email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="{{email}}">

    <div><input type="submit" value="Okay"></div>
    <div class = "stat">{{stat}}</div>
    <div class="error">{{error}}</div> 
</form>
```

When I remove

```
user = ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name = "sells")
```

and just commit user and sell, the page displays. What is this line messing up the page?

Edit:
The indentation is from copy and paste and is right in the code. In the Handler class that I inherit from I have

```
def render(self, template, **kw):
    self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
```

so the problem should not be in the get method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just found the bug. forgot to put "db." before ReferenceProperty. LOL

Answer (score 1):

Your get method should be something like this:

```
def get(self):
    f=open('sell.html','r')
    sourceHtml = unicode(f.read(),errors='ignore')
    f.close()
    self.response.write(sourceHtml)
```

I also see indentation issues. The class Sell is aligned to the same level as the get() method. The method should be one level inside.